# Extract records from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to display the records of one dataset that are not in another dataset.

Here is the code for the larger dataset:

```
select distinct facil_identifier, facil_addr_line1,
trim(facil_city) as facil_city, facil_zip
from xx.tb1 f
where facil_identifier is not null
```

I would like to find the records in the first(larger) dataset that are not in the smaller dataset.

Here is the code for the smaller dataset:

```
select distinct facil_identifier, facil_addr_line1,
facil_zip
from xx.tb1 f
where facil_identifier is not null
```

This is my attempt:

```
select distinct facil_identifier, facil_addr_line1,
facil_zip
from xx.tb1 f
where facil_identifier is not null
and facil_identifier not in
(select facil_identifier
from 
    (select distinct facil_identifier, facil_addr_line1,
    trim(facil_city) as facil_city, facil_zip
    from xx.tb1 f2
    where facil_identifier is not null) as city
where city.facil_identifier = f.facil_identifier)
order by facil_addr_line1
```

This code has enormous cost. There are less than 3000 records in each set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on postgres SQL, but this should do it (or at least get you close)

```
select distinct f2.facil_identifier, f2.facil_addr_line1,
trim(f2.facil_city) as facil_city, f2.facil_zip
from import.facil_xx_20131016 f2
left join import.facil_xx_20131016 f on f2.facil_identifier = f.facil_identifier
where f2.facil_identifier is not null
and f.facil_identifier is null
```

Comment: Left join results in all records in the larger set.

Comment: @user1850180 That's why there is the "f.facil_identifier is null" in the where clause.  It will join all the records in the larger set with their accompanying records of the smaller set.  That part of the where clause tells it to filter out all the records that have a corresponding record in the smaller set.

Comment: I either return the entire larger set or 0 records.

Comment: @user1850180 I've made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eb82/1) that does what you are looking for but with a simpler data set and schema.  I am betting you have a typo somewhere in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The difference between the sample and my query is that when I select distinct records based on the identifier, street address, city, and zip there are more records returned than if I select distinct records based on the identifier, street address, and zip. Thanks again.

Comment: @swhit First, you shouldn't need all the subqueries in there.  Secondly, you are getting records from the same table in both subqueries.  Since you are doing that, (instead of using the other table in the second subquery) you are asking the DB for all the records in the big set that don't exist in the big set (which will always be nothing).